# Convert array of observables of observables to array of observables rxjs

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

To simplify the problem i have used numbers and strings here. The code:

```
const numbers$:Observable<number[]> = of([1,2,3]);
const strings: string[] = ["a","b"];

function getStrings(): Observable<string>[]{
   return numbers$.pipe( 
     map((numbers: number[]) => {
       const strings$: Observable<string>[] =  strings.map(s => of(s));
       return strings$;
     }),
  )
}

getStrings().subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

The error i am getting is:
`Type 'Observable<Observable<string>[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<string>[]`
How can i get `Observable<string>[]` from `getStrings` function? I have tried to use flatMap, switchMap but unable to get the perfect combination.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-zasjud?embed=1&file=index.ts)

Comment: Try using `mergeMap` instead of `map`.

Comment: didn't solve the problem

Comment: Using `Observable<string>[]` means an array of `Observable<string>` which is not what you're returning right now. Maybe you wanted this instead `Observable<string[]>`?

Comment: No i want ```Observable<string>[]``` because in my application i will use this in ```forkJoin```

Comment: @martin You are right, i want ```Observable<string[]>```, not ```Observable<string>[]```

Comment: Maybe like this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-dzvsbh?file=index.ts

Comment: Yes. You can post it as answer. Thanks @martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `mergeMap()` and `forkJoin()`:

```
function getStrings(): Observable<string[]>{
   return numbers$.pipe( 
     mergeMap((numbers: number[]) => {
       const strings$: Observable<string>[] =  strings.map(s => of(s));
       return forkJoin(strings$);
     }),
  )
}

getStrings().subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-dzvsbh?file=index.ts

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand you want to "zip" two lists together, via observable ?

I can offer you this one

```js
    const numbers$: Observable<number[]> = of([1, 2, 3]);
    const strings$: Observable<string[]> = of(['a', 'b']);

    const combined$: Observable<any> = zip(numbers$, strings$)
      .pipe(
        map(([numbers, strings]) =>
          numbers.length > strings.length ?
            numbers.map((value, index) => [value, strings[index]]) :
            strings.map((value, index) => [numbers[index], value]))
      );

    combined$.subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

This will log: 
[
  [
    1,
    "a"
  ],
  [
    2,
    "b"
  ],
  [
    3,
    null
  ]
]

Comment: Basically no, because in real example strings$ is dependent on numbers$ response.

Comment: @Aamir ok, sorry for misunderstanding :)